# Wordpress ajax post to same page - with only admin panel access

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I only have admin panel access (no file level access) to a wordpress site. I am adding php code using this plugin [Shortcode Exec PHP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-exec-php/) and adding my jquery into the text editor.

Everything is working fine. But now that I want to have an ajax call where my ajax post url will be `window.location.href` and will point to the code within my shortcode exec php `if(isset($_POST)){ echo "Yes!" }` , I am getting the entire page as a response. Note that I am new to wordpress and testing using a draft.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Appreciate suggestions on better practices to achieve this. Following is my code:

//jquery

```
  $.ajax(
                   {
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: window.location.href,
                       dataType: 'json',
                       cache: false,
                       data:{
                         action: 'test'
                       },
                       success: function(response)
                       {
                          alert('success');

                       },
                       error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
                       {
                           alert('error');
                       }
                   });
```

//php

```
if(isset($_POST)){ echo "Yes!"; return "true"; }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
The statndard way to interact with ajax in Wordpress through WP AJAX.You can do like this.

$.ajax(
       {
           type: 'POST',
           url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=your_action_name",
           dataType: 'json',
           cache: false,
           data:{
            your data should be here
           },
           success: function(response)
           {
              alert('success');

           },
           error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
           {
               alert('error');
           }
});

then in functions.php or plugin file you need to register a hook for ajax request.wp_ajax should be prefix your action hook name and then method for processing the request.

add_action('wp_ajax','method_name');
function method_name(){
here is your code

}
```

Comment: thanks. but i dont have access to the project files. i only have access to the wordpress admin panel. so the only way i need to get it done is using php plugin to embed php code and find a workaround with js to reach that code on same page. any idea?

Comment: Then you can easily add the below to the plugin file which has plugin header.


add_action('wp_ajax','method_name');
function method_name(){
here is your code

}

Comment: it's the same what @go4glory has suggested. but still didnt work. it's returning me the whole html. In fact, it is not enter the ajax success callback, it's going into error

Comment: @aiiwa you need to use exit at the end of your ajax processing code and also echo the response there then it can be accessed as response in ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right on client side(JQuery).

But in wordpress you can't check a request using **isset**.

For that you have to implement like this:

As you have declared **test as action** in your example.

```
  //For example wp_ajax_**Your_Action**

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_test', 'test_callback' );

    function test_callback(){
      //implement your code     
    }
```

Comment: tried this, still getting the full page. note that the url that i am posting to is something like this http://[mydomain]/?page_id=125&preview=true